# Hadoop: How to configure failover time for a datanode

Tags: failover, hadoop, hdfs

I need to re-replicate blocks on my HDFS cluster in case of a datanode is failing. Actually, this appears to already happen after a period of maybe 10min. However, I want to decrease this time, but wondering how to do so.

I tried to set `dfs.namenode.check.stale.datanode` but w/o any big success. So what is the configrations options or what are the options I have to adjust here to maybe decrease it to 1min?

The complete section out of hdfs-site.xml looks like this

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.check.stale.datanode</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Activate stale check</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval</name>
    <value>10</value>
    <description>Timeout</description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an discussion on [hadoop-user-mailing-list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-user/201501.mbox/browser) it appears that `dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval` needs to be set inside `hdfs-site.xml`. The time until a datanode is marked as dead is calculate from this time in combination with `dfs.heartbeat.interval`. In fact a configuration

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval</name>
    <value>10000</value>
</property>
```

Resulted in ~45s until node has been marked dead. (this applies to 2.6 of Hadoop)